# What we can not do with ASP.net AJAX, when to use pure js AJAX

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

Can some one give me some examples to prove when to use Pure JS AJAX in Asp.Net application. Can we accomplish everything with ASP.Net AJAX controls?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

asp.net uses script manager and update panel for ajax effects.

update panel is not pure ajax , it creates an illusiion of ajax .

for more information you can see here http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers

Comment: Thanks. My question is, from the functionality perspective, whatever we can do with pure AJAX, can we accomplish all these with ASP.net AJAX? I mean, Is there any functionality if we need to implement in ASP.net, we will have to go with pure AJAX and can not be done by using ASP.net AJAX?

Comment: @Akie no you can only do what asp.net ajax controls can do. this is why Microsoft had  included support for jquery